# How to make string sequence by mapping in scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala

```
object NGram{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      //args(0) = textfile //args(1) = size of n-grams //args(2) = the number of words to generate
        val F = scala.io.Source.fromFile(args(0)) // take from args[0]
        for (line <- F.getLines()){
        val words = line.split("[ ,:;.?!-]+") map (_.toLowerCase)
        var ngram : Set[String] = Set()
        //make n-gram
        for(i <- 0 to words.size - args(1)) {
          // first make sequence by args(1)
          for(j <- i until i + args(1)){
            ngram = ngram + words(j) // not works it is my problem stage
          }


          }
        }
    }
}
```

I made n-gram algorithm by using scala. at first

1. make string sequence, and check it is in original string.
2. and It is efficiently works.

I want n string sequence not duplicated (because it must work efficiently)

How to make n string sequence by map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I correct that :

- you have a sequence of words (not sure from your code whether it should be a single line or the full file)
- an n-gram is a sequence of n words consecutive in the original sequence
- you want a certain number of distinct n-gram.

There is a routine that will give you n-grams, it is `sliding`. 
with

```
val words = Seq("the", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog")
val trigrams = words.sliding(3).toSeq
foreach(triGram in triGrams) println(triGram.mkString(" "))
```

> ```
> the brown fox
> brown fox jumps
> fox jumps over
> jumps over the
> over the lazy
> the lazy dog
> ```

There is a caveat, if you have only p words and want n-grams, with n > p, sliding will return  one p-gram (not an n-gram obviously) rather than none. So you have to check for that.

You can do `toSet` rather than `toSeq` to eliminate duplicates.

There is the last point, you want only a certain number of n-grams (your last argument). You did not specify how you want to select them. The simple way would be a take. To avoid to  go through the whole list of words, and take the `count` first distinct one, that would be

```
words.sliding(n).toStream.distinct.take(count)
```

If you want to take them at random position, that is a different story and maybe `sliding` is not the way to go.